# How to display one div and hide everythng else in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display only one image from HTML and hide everything else using javascript.

The structure of **HTML**:

```
<body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
            <img id="nameOfImg">
        </div>
        <div/>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

I iterated through the `document.body.children` and hid everything except my image and it did work, but unfortunately the scructure of html has changed meanwhile. So I try to find different solution, more robust for changes in html.

My new idea is this:

```
function showImage(idName) {
    document.body.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(idName).parentElement.style.display ='block'
    }
```

But that displays nothing.

Comment: Since the body(parent) itself is hidden, you making the div(child) visible is not going to have any impact. since the actual hiding deals with the body and not with the divs

Comment: Can be done with a few lines of CSS as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this. It loop through all `div` and check if the `div` contain your image or not, if it not then hide it.

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var img = document.getElementById("nameOfImg");

for(var el of els) {
  if (!el.contains(img)) el.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <img id="nameOfImg" alt="img" src="test">
    </div>
    <div/>
</div>
<div>7</div>
```